# Use of including instead of with

Tags: prepositions

> I'd really be a fool not to because $463,000 sounds like a lot, but after taxes it will barely buy you a new refrigerator **with delivery** and installation in Manhattan.

Would it be correct if I use “including” instead of with in this sentence ? If it is correct wihich one would be more formal?

Comment: Are refrigerators really that expensive in the USA? Or taxes so high?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "formal"? This sentence is **very** informal to begin with and would need to be rewritten completely to be formal. "With" is used idiomatically here: see [this definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/what-with).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey This is hyperbole of course, but Manhattan is a ridiculously expensive place to live!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey [$50,000 refrigerator](https://www.williams-sonoma.com/products/smeg-giuseppe-garibaldi-the-hero-dolce-and-gabbana-refrigerator/?catalogId=22&sku=942927&cm_ven=PLA&cm_cat=Google&cm_pla=Electrics%20%3E%20Refrigerators&cm_ite=942927&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIx77kiumV6AIVUxx9Ch1hXAqrEAQYASABEgI1dvD_BwE), plus ~1000% tax...seems about right.

Comment: @TypeIA I just want to learn if I can use “including “ in this sentence.

Comment: Perhaps "excluding delivery and installation" would be apt.

Answer (score 1):

"Including" and "with" would have the same meaning in this sentence.

"Including" might be clearer in some cases and so would probably be preferred in more formal contexts, but as pointed out in the comments, the example given is so informal that any difference in formality is irrelevant in **this** case.